# differences between a Pandas dataframe and Geopandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I have used Pandas a lot but recently completed a project with Geopandas for the first time. There was a dataframe of POIs which had various data columns including a Latitude and a Longitude column and that was converted into a Geopandas dataframe which now included a 'projection' applied to the whole dataframe and also included a 'geometry' column with `POINTS` objects each of which contained a pair of coordinates, no doubt a projection of the latitude and longitude.

Can this geopandas dataframe now be *safely* recycled for general pandas use, add additional columns and do operations with it which have nothing more to do with geographic matters or will that run into problems?

What are otherwise the differences between the Pandas dataframe and Geopandas dataframe?

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` vs.  `<class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>`

Comment: This type of comparison question is great for ChatGPT [answer](https://chat.openai.com/share/ad2ba50b-2dad-4923-a407-c2e016798ee8). The posted answer is likely AI generated, which is a violation of the ToS.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwp8b.png) of the ChatGPT4 output. If I delete the query from my profile, the link in the previous comment will be useless. The input query was the text of the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a geopandas geodataframe into a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504886/converting-a-geopandas-geodataframe-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR:

There are no noticeable differences, apart from perhaps different commands for [reading](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html)/[saving](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_file.html) the dataframe.

### Longer form:

#### 1. "Can this geopandas dataframe now be safely recycled for general pandas use, add additional columns and do operations with it which have nothing more to do with geographic matters or will that run into problems?"

You can pretty much use Pandas and GeoPandas interchangeably.

GeoPandas sort of acts as an *extension* of the Pandas module, with the definition given inside the code being:

> [A GeoDataFrame object is a pandas.DataFrame that has a column with geometry.](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/main/geopandas/geodataframe.py#L72)

As said, the key benefit being the aforementioned 'geometry' column, which you can easily view with an `.iloc` to see a picture of what the geometry looks like for that row.

As a result, it's very unlikely you'll run into any compatibility issue, though you need to be aware of minor differences, e.g:

- Pandas: `.read_csv`, `.write_csv`
- GeoPandas: `.read_file`, `.to_file`

If you encounter a difficulty it should be easy to fix by searching the [geopandas docs](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs.html)

#### 2. "What are otherwise the differences between the Pandas dataframe and Geopandas dataframe?"

To fill in further from the codebase:

> In addition to the standard DataFrame constructor arguments,
> GeoDataFrame also accepts the following keyword arguments:

```
Parameters
----------
crs : value (optional)
    Coordinate Reference System of the geometry objects. Can be anything accepted by
    :meth:`pyproj.CRS.from_user_input() <pyproj.crs.CRS.from_user_input>`,
    such as an authority string (eg "EPSG:4326") or a WKT string.
geometry : str or array (optional)
    If str, column to use as geometry. If array, will be set as 'geometry'
    column on GeoDataFrame.
```

So the only other thing to mention is the CRS value that lets you instruct the frame what type of reference system to use for the geometry, you should probably be able to tell if you aren't using the standard CRS (WGS 84/EPSG:4326) as your geometry will look very strange, otherwise you won't really need to care about it.